# struts2 helloWorld --> show 404 error

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, struts2

I have put my struts2 helloWorld code. When run on weblogic server 10.3.6, click on index.jsp page, it show 404 error. 
It should process the hello action but not. 
Is there any missing in my code. Please help.

aeon_awip_application

+---src

+---src---com.tutorialspoint.strut2(package)---HelloWorldAction.java

+---src---struts.xml

+---WebContent

+---WebContent---index.jsp

+---WebContent---WEB-INF---web.xml, weblogic.xml

+---WebContent---WEB-INF---helloWorld---HelloWorld.jsp

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
   <form action="hello">
      <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
   </form>
</body>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" metadata-complete="true" version="2.5">
  <display-name>aeon_awip_application</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="hello"
            class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">helloWorld/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: You got wrong tutorial, drop it and start a new one or better follow struts project examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it due to jar problems. I have not used the maven and used the lib folder in which I copied the jars according to the tuto